# Can anyone take the for loop out of this code?

Tags: php

Can anyone refactor this code without the for loop?

```
<?php

function lorem($paragraph_count = 1, $times = 1, $content = '')
{
    $paragraph = array(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ......... Fusce a ante.",
        "Praesent sit amet est. Vestibulum quis elit ......... consectetuer quis, quam.",
        "Suspendisse ac eros. Morbi ......... feugiat at, tincidunt eget, ante.",
        "Proin sit amet ......... nisi lacinia tristique.",
        "Vivamus eu nisl sit amet tortor euismod venenatis ......... Proin tortor. Integer pulvinar."
    );

    for($i = 0; $i <= $paragraph_count; $i++) $content .= "<p>{$paragraph[$i]}</p>\n";

    return str_repeat($content, $times);
}
?>

<?= lorem(2,2); ?>
```

Comment: Is your end goal readability/maintainability, or performance (or both)?

Comment: Performance but condensed code... ruby oneliner style!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone better refactor this php lorem generator?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/can-anyone-better-refactor-this-php-lorem-generator)

Comment: The title of your post should be the function/purpose of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The following replaces the loop using higher-order functions:

```
$para = function($p) { return "<p>$p</p>\n"; };
$content = implode('', array_map($para, array_slice($paragraphs, 0,  $paragraph_count)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_slice` to return a narrow selection from an array:

```
function random_paragraphs  (array $chunks, $length=1) {
    shuffle($chunks);
    return '<p>'.
    implode(
        '</p><p>',
        array_slice(
            $chunks, 
            0,
            (count($chunks) > $length ? $length : count($chunks))
        )
    ).
    '</p>';
}

echo random_paragraphs($paragraph, 5);
```

**Documentation**

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Another alternative I'm trying is array_filter() with a closure or lamba but not working yet

Comment: For an ugly 1 liner: return array_reduce( array_slice($paragraph, 0, $paragraph_count), function ($a, $b) { return "<p>{$a}{$b}</p>\n"; } );

Comment: `array_filter` is not an appropriate function for this use. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I deal with arrays seemingly every 2nd line, from MySQL results, mongo sets etc... and always using foreach to iterate/modify/parse array keys/elements... I'm looking for alternative functions/ways of doing it so not always using the foreach albeit it's fit. I know it does what it says on the tin but it's getting like rape trains in COD Zombies! Just looking for slick alternatives... yeah array_filter wudn't work unless array_filter( array_flip($array) ). I really appreciate the feedback and Thanks :) Just trying to accomplish alternatives that are viable.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, any iterative loop can be recreated using recursion, and vice-versa. That said, you don't necessarily want to use recursion to solve most problems. Here is the recursive form, however:

```
function lorem($paragraph_count = 1, $times = 1, $content = '') {
    $paragraph = array(
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ......... Fusce a ante.",
        "Praesent sit amet est. Vestibulum quis elit ......... consectetuer quis, quam.",
        "Suspendisse ac eros. Morbi ......... feugiat at, tincidunt eget, ante.",
        "Proin sit amet ......... nisi lacinia tristique.",
        "Vivamus eu nisl sit amet tortor euismod venenatis ......... Proin tortor. Integer pulvinar."
    );

    // Build a base body of text with the desired number of entries from lorem ipsum
    if ($paragraph_count > 0) {
        $content = "<p>{$paragraph[$paragraph_count-1]}</p>\n"+ $content;
        return lorem($paragraph_count-1, $times, $content);
    }

    // Regular base case
    if ($times <= 1) {
        return $content;
    }

    // Repeat the base body of text we built
    return $content + lorem($paragraph_count, $times-1, $content);
}

echo lorem(2,2);
```

I'd stick with the iterative version.

p.s. sorry if there are any typos, I typed it up in python then changed to php syntax : (

Comment: Thanks for the reply James... definitely a contender... never thought of calling the __ FUNCTION __ again with new arg values